# Suddenly getting an error "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" in VB.net with Oracle 11g Database

Tags: oracle, vb.net, datareader

A batch job runs at every night and it had been successed until yesterday.

It gave this exception, "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object",suddenly today. I didn't change any codes. (Actually I didn't write this code, someone did)

I don't get it at all, what is it happening?

I can't specify whether it comes from its environment, code or data.

Only I can say was that this error occurred at this line
Dim rotate As Short = DirectCast(dr("ROTATE"), Short)

Stacktrace from log:

Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.get_Item(String columnName)
MyProject.Package.Filing.Core.Yakan.LinkDataCreate.ImageCreateWorker.Execute(Object obj)

I need some help.

This is my code:

```
   Public Sub Execute(ByVal obj As Object)

    Dim errorCount As Integer = 0

    ' 2018/06/18
    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::Execute(),開始")

    Do
        If errorCount >= Me._retryCount Then
            Dim message As String = String.Format("Worker処理でエラーが発生しました。基準年：{0}、IJP：{1}", Me._kijunNen, Me._ijp)
            Dim newEx As FilingException = New FilingException(message, String.Empty)
            LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Error, newEx, String.Empty)
            Throw newEx
        End If

        'イメージは順次取得する。
        Using agent As New ImageCommandAgent
            agent.Kijun_nen = Me._kijunNen
            agent.HonpyoIJP = Me._ijp
            agent.IsRyomen = Me._isRyomen

            Using codec As New Codecs.RasterCodecs()

                ' ディスクメモリ使用フラグ
                codec.Options.Load.DiskMemory = Me._diskMemoryFlg

                Dim image As RasterImage = Nothing

                ' 2018/06/19
                LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::Execute() ExecuteReader,開始")

                Using dr As System.Data.Common.DbDataReader = agent.ExecuteReader(Me._dbConnection)

                    ' 2018/06/19
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, String.Format("ImageCreateWorker::Execute() ExecuteReader,終了,IJP:{0}", agent.HonpyoIJP))

                    Try
                        While dr.Read()

                            ' 2018/06/19
                            LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::Execute() IMAGE_DATA MemoryStream,開始")

                            Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(DirectCast(dr("IMAGE_DATA"), Byte())), _
                                  singleImage As RasterImage = codec.Load(ms)

                                ' 2018/06/19
                                LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, String.Format("ImageCreateWorker::Execute() IMAGE_DATA MemoryStream,終了,IJP:{0}", agent.HonpyoIJP))
                                'I get an exception here
                                **Dim rotate As Short = DirectCast(dr("ROTATE"), Short)**
                                If rotate <> 0 Then

                                    ' 2018/06/19
                                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::Execute() Rotate,開始")

                                    Dim Rcommand As RotateCommand = New RotateCommand()
                                    Rcommand.Angle = rotate * 9000
                                    Rcommand.Run(singleImage)

                                    ' 2018/06/19
                                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, String.Format("ImageCreateWorker::Execute() Rotate,終了,IJP:{0}", agent.HonpyoIJP))

                                End If

                                'グレースケールに変換してから本体に追加する。

                                ' 2018/06/19
                                LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::Execute() Grayscale,開始")

                                Dim command As New GrayscaleCommand()
                                command.BitsPerPixel = 8
                                command.Run(singleImage)

                                ' 2018/06/19
                                LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, String.Format("ImageCreateWorker::Execute() Grayscale,終了,IJP:{0}", agent.HonpyoIJP))

                                If image Is Nothing Then
                                    image = singleImage.CloneAll    '最初の一枚
                                Else
                                    ' 2018/06/19
                                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::Execute() AddPage,開始")

                                    image.AddPage(singleImage) '追加

                                    ' 2018/06/19
                                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, String.Format("ImageCreateWorker::Execute() AddPage,終了,IJP:{0}", agent.HonpyoIJP))

                                End If

                            End Using
                        End While

                    Catch ex As System.Exception
                        ' 異常終了
                        If Not image Is Nothing Then
                            image.Dispose()
                            image = Nothing
                        End If

                        Dim message As String = String.Format("【警告】帳票イメージの取得に失敗しました。基準年：{0}、IJP：{1}", Me._kijunNen, Me._ijp)
                        Dim newEx As FilingException = New FilingException(message, ex, String.Empty)
                        LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Warning, newEx, String.Empty)
                        LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Warning, ex.Message)
                        LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Warning, ex.StackTrace)

                        errorCount = errorCount + 1
                        Continue Do

                    End Try
                End Using ' ■■ datareader ■■

                Try
                    ' 2018/06/19
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::Execute() フォルダ検索,開始")

                    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(PathName) Then
                        CreateDirectory(PathName)
                    End If

                    ' 2018/06/19
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, String.Format("ImageCreateWorker::Execute() フォルダ検索,終了,IJP:{0}", agent.HonpyoIJP))

                    ' 2018/06/19
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::Execute() ファイル検索,開始")

                    If IO.File.Exists(FileFullPath) Then
                        ' saveメソッドでは上書き不可のため、消しておく
                        IO.File.Delete(FileFullPath)
                    End If

                    ' 2018/06/19
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, String.Format("ImageCreateWorker::Execute() ファイル検索,終了,IJP:{0}", agent.HonpyoIJP))

                    ' 2018/06/19
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::Execute() イメージ保存,開始")

                    Select Case ImageMode
                        Case "BINARY"
                            '’■■二値のマルチTIFで保存する場合■■
                            codec.Save(image, FileFullPath, RasterImageFormat.CcittGroup4, 1)

                        Case "BINARY-DITH"
                            '' ■■ディザリングを指定して二値で保存する場合■■
                            image.DitheringMethod = RasterDitheringMethod.FloydStein
                            codec.Options.Save.UseImageDitheringMethod = True
                            codec.Save(image, FileFullPath, RasterImageFormat.CcittGroup4, 1)

                        Case "GRAY"
                            '' ■■グレースケールのマルチTIFで保存する場合■■
                            codec.Options.Jpeg.Save.QualityFactor = 255
                            codec.Save(image, FileFullPath, RasterImageFormat.TifJpeg, 8)

                        Case Else
                            '' その他の場合、おすすめのグレーで保存します。
                            codec.Options.Jpeg.Save.QualityFactor = 255
                            codec.Save(image, FileFullPath, RasterImageFormat.TifJpeg, 8)

                    End Select

                    ' 2018/06/19
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, String.Format("ImageCreateWorker::Execute() イメージ保存,終了,IJP:{0}", agent.HonpyoIJP))

                Catch ex As System.Exception
                    ' 異常終了
                    If Not image Is Nothing Then
                        image.Dispose()
                        image = Nothing
                    End If

                    Dim message As String = String.Format("【警告】イメージファイルの出力に失敗しました。基準年：{0}、IJP：{1}", Me._kijunNen, Me._ijp)
                    Dim newEx As FilingException = New FilingException(message, ex, String.Empty)
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Warning, newEx, String.Empty)
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Warning, ex.Message)
                    LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Warning, ex.StackTrace)

                    errorCount = errorCount + 1
                    Continue Do
                Finally
                    If Not image Is Nothing Then
                        image.Dispose()
                        image = Nothing
                    End If
                End Try

                ' 2018/06/18
                LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, String.Format("ImageCreateWorker::Execute(),終了,IJP:{0}", Me._ijp))

                Exit Do

            End Using ' codec
        End Using ' agent
    Loop

    ' スレッド終了通知
    ' 2019/11/03 try-catch にして例外を取得する
    'OnFinishedEventHandler(EventArgs.Empty)
    Try
        LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Information, "ImageCreateWorker::スレッドの終了通知")
        OnFinishedEventHandler(EventArgs.Empty)

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        Dim message As String = "スレッドの終了通知に失敗"
        Dim newEx As FilingException = New FilingException(message, ex, String.Empty)
        LogManager.GetLogger.PutLog(LogLevel.Warning, newEx, String.Empty)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the value of Rotate actually a short int? Could it be an int32 instead of an int16? What is the datatype of that column in your DB?

Comment: How long does this process take?   And what exact is calling it?  What exactly is ImageCommandAgent?  Is that a wrapper for a DB connection.  Is this exception happening on the first iteration of `While dr.Read()` or the nth iteration?

Comment: the datatype is NUMBER(1,0).  I checked the record giving me the error and its value is 0 or 3

Comment: @Hursey
Normally it takes about 30 minute (depending on the amount of data) but in this case it ended within 1min cause exception occurred. 

A middleware calls this process. 

As you say, imageCommandAgent is  a wrapper for DB connection.

I think it was not happening on the first iteration because from log I saw some data was processed.

Comment: So likely cause in my mind is the data being retrieved by the data reader.  Perhaps start by looking at the source data, maybe running the same query directly against the db and inspect results.  My guess is you've got some malformed data in there of some nature